# Let $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2x}\mathbb{1}_D(x,y)$ with $D = \{(x,y) : 1\leq x \leq 3, 0 \leq y \leq x \}$

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2x}\mathbb{1}_D(x,y)$ with $D = \{(x,y) : 1\leq x \leq 3, 0 \leq y \leq x \}$.

I want to calculate the probability that $2y > 3 - x$, I set up my integral like this: 
$$ \int_{1}^{3}\int_{-\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{2}}^{x} \frac{1}{2x} dy dx$$
Is that right? My question is: how do I find $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$? 
I tried writing: 
$$ f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{2x}dy$$
But that doesn't look too good to me, plus I don't know to set up the other one. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of the probability looks fine.

$$f_X(x) = \int_0^x \frac1{2x}\, dy = \frac{x}{2x}=\frac12$$

We have

$$f_Y(y) = \int_{\max(1, y)}^3 \frac1{2x} \, dx$$

Comment: I don't understand how you found $f_Y(y)$, could you go a little bit in depth?

Comment: If we want to compute $f_Y$, we integrate with respect to $x$, if we want to compute $f_X$, we integrate with respect to $y$.

Comment: Yes, but why the max(1,y)? I would have put just 1 instead.

Comment: have u sketch out the feasible region?

Comment: Yep, it is a trapezoid of vertices (1,0), (3,0), (3,3) and (1,1)

Comment: Consider if $y=2$, what is the lower bound for the value of $x$ for its' density value to take positive value?